# Apache Spark partitions distribution strategy

Tags: apache-spark

There are partitioning strategies in Apache Spark. Hash partitioning, Range partitioning and an ability to write custom partitioners. But how are partitions distribute by cluster nodes? Is there a way to affect this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partitions distribution in Spark relies on the data source and on your configuration. The partitioners you quote are used during manual repartitioning operations, such as *coalesce* or *repartition*. When you decide to do so, Spark will sometimes shuffle the data between nodes (if shuffle flat set to true). The partitioners are also used in some RDD-based operations, as for instance *RDD.sortByKey* that looks like:

```
def sortByKey(ascending: Boolean = true, numPartitions: Int = self.partitions.length): RDD[(K, V)] = self.withScope 
{ 
   val part = new RangePartitioner(numPartitions, self, ascending)
   new ShuffledRDD[K, V, V](self, part).setKeyOrdering(if (ascending) ordering else ordering.reverse)
}
```

Regarding the partitions during data reading, it depends on source types. For Kafka, it'll be the partitions of a topic, for HDFS a file split and for an RDBMS source a numerical column and AFAIK, the partitioners aren't involved here. 
Some time ago I wrote some posts about partitioning in Spark (and in Spark SQL). If you're interested, you can take a look:

- http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/partitioning-in-spark/read
- http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/partitioning-internals-spark/read
- http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/partitioning-rdbms-data-spark-sql-jdbc/read